# How to retrieve blob data sent over API call in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, blob

From ReactJS I have sent blob data through API call and my Node server is listening on that port.

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav'});
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('audio', audioBlob);
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/generateConsolidatedAudio', {
data: fd });
```

Node JS:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
router.post('/generateConsolidatedAudio', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Hello Gi');
}));
```

I did `console.log(req.body)` and `console.log(req.data)` but both were `undefined`.

I want to fetch the blob from it and convert that into an WAV file. Please any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better convert the blob to file and sent the file

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav'});
var audioFile = new File([audioBlob], "name");
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('audio', audioFile);
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/generateConsolidatedAudio', {
data: fd });
```

Now in Nodejs You can't handle files or mutipart data using `body-parser`. So use multer `npm i multer`

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I am able to download that file to my directory. Can I use this code in production since my application is working in IBM cloud and my usecase is that I want to concat multiple audio files into one single file. Do you have any idea?